# Find the area bounded by the curves $x^3$ and $x^4$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.5

Can somebody verify this solution for me? Thanks!

Find the area bounded by the curves $x^3$ and $x^4$ on $(0,1)$.

First we have to solve $x^3=x^4$ to find the bounds of integration.

$x^3=x^4$

$ \rightarrow 0 = x^4-x^3$

$\rightarrow 0 = x^3(x-1)$

and so $x=0$ and $x=1$ are solutions.

Furthermore, on the interval $(0,1)$ we have that $x^4<x^3$. The area between the graphs is thus:

$\int_0^1 x^3-x^4 dx$

$= \frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}|_0^1$

$= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} - 0 - 0$

$= \frac{1}{20}$

Comment: Yes, it seems okay to me.

Comment: @MSV All good :)